# Django some URLs don't work

Tags: python, django

I've been making some URLs in Django, including them and so on. Everything looks fine, but no matter what i do i always end up with a 404 on some of the simplest URLs.

For example I can browse `myapp/0` abd `myapp/1/details/`, but i get 404'd at `myapp/foo`

So here are my urlconf :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

and myapp urlconf :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^foo/$ ', FooView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<bar_id>\d+)/$', BarByIdView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<bar_id>\d+)/details/$', BarDetailsByIdView.as_view()),
]
```

And when i tryp `myapp/foo` Django shows me the following urls list :

```
^admin/
^myapp/ ^foo/$
^myapp/ ^(?P<bar_id>\d+)/$
^myapp/ ^(?P<bar_id>\d+)/details/$
```

Comment: I think you are missing a slash while browsing the page. It should be `myapp/foo/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `myapp.conf` you have added a `/` at the end of the `url` pattern

```
url(r'^foo/$ ', FooView.as_view()
```

This must be viewed with `/myapp/foo/` and not `/myapp/foo` because the first one matches the regex where as the second one won't.

Comment: @Jivay make sure that the url ends with slash \ and nothing follows there after, not even space

Comment: I double checked, and now it works, even though nothing has changed. Poof. Magic. 3 hours of time lost.
You sir are a wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is `/myapp/foo/`, not `/myapp/foo`. Note the trailing slash.

If you want both to work, ensure you have the [`APPEND_SLASH` setting](http://www.djangoproject.dev:8000/fundraising) set to True and the `CommonMiddleware` enabled.